# why http://localhost:10007/web/example/ is giving empty response in Corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I Started with cordapp set up. I am able to build corapp-example as in the set up instruction.
To test when I opened above link its not working?
Should I do any other set up

Comment: Do you have seven terminal windows running after doing the `runNodes` step? Are there any error messages in the terminal windows?

Comment: I have did setup in IntelliJ, and build is success without any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the docs that is being addressed.

When running via IntelliJ, the webports for the nodes are http://localhost:10009/, http://localhost:10012/ and http://localhost:10015/.